# How to achieve 6k @ 60Hz on Mac Pro 5,1 with RX 6600?

Tags: display, hdmi, displayport, mac-pro

I have a Mac Pro 5,1 running macOS Monterey via Open Core Legacy Patcher (OCLP) and I just purchased a flashed [RX 6600 video card](https://www.macvidcards.eu/products/amd-radeon-rx6600-8-gb-gddr6-2) from [MacVidCards.eu](https://www.macvidcards.eu/). According to the specs on the MacVidCards website, the card is capable of 8k @ 60Hz. The card I purchased appears to be a flashed [XFX Speedster SWFT 210 AMD Radeon™ RX 6600](https://www.xfxforce.com/shop/xfx-speedster-swft-210-amd-radeon-tm-rx-6600-core#2) with the following ports:

> ‍DisplayPort: 1.4 with DSC
> HDMI™: 2.1 VRR and FRL

The manufacturer website does not include maximum resolution in the specs, but the [same card by Sapphire](https://www.sapphiretech.com/en/consumer/pulse-radeon-rx-6600-8g-gddr6#Specification) does:

> HDMI™: 7680×4320
> DisplayPort1.4: 7680×4320

So I have no reason to believe this card should be incapable of achieving 6k @ 60Hz.

My monitor is a [Dell UltraSharp 32" 6K HDR Video Conferencing Monitor](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1768651-REG/dell_u3224kb_32_6k_60hz_hdr600.html). It is capable of 6K 6144 x 3456 at 60 Hz. In addition to Thunderbolt 4, it has the following video inputs:

> HDMI 2.1
> Mini DisplayPort 2.1

I have purchased 3 different video cables:

- 8k mDP 1.4 cable: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0CL6GH63X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0CL6GH63X)
- 16k mDP 2.1 cable: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0CHVSPNCZ](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0CHVSPNCZ)
- 8k HDMI 2.1 cable: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B09CHH8TRC](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09CHH8TRC)

Using either of the 2 mDP cables connected to my PC with an RX 2080ti, the monitor reports a resolution of 6k @ 60Hz, 24-bit:

[image: 6k @ 60Hz, 24-bit]

Using the HDMI cable on the PC with the 2080ti, I get 4k @ 60Hz, 24-bit:

[image: 4k @ 60Hz, 24-bit]

Now, using the same DP cables connected to the RX 6600 in the Mac, the monitor will only sync to 5k @ 60Hz, 24-bit:

[image: 5k @ 60Hz, 24-bit]

Finally, using the same HDMI cable connected to the RX 6600 in the Mac, the monitor will only sync to 5k @ 60Hz, 30-bit:

[image: 5k @ 60Hz, 30-bit]

While connected to HDMI, running the following command on Terminal results in the following output:

`system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType |grep Resolution`

> 2024-03-31 12:30:55.464 system_profiler[43589:961215] Device PreExisted [000000010000076f] AMD Radeon RX 6600
> Resolution: 5120 x 2880 (5K/UHD+ - Ultra High Definition Plus)

Since posting this question, I also found something interesting. While using HDMI, I can increase the resolution (scale up??) to what "looks like"  3008 x 1692 (have been running 5k with what "looks like" 2560 x 1440). Running the `system_profiler` command again, here's what I found:

> 2024-03-31 12:37:46.658 system_profiler[43745:966153] Device PreExisted [000000010000076f] AMD Radeon RX 6600
> Resolution: 6016 x 3384

The screen still looks clear, and here's what System Profiler shows:

[image]

But, the monitor is still only connected/synced to the computer at 5k:

[image: 5k @ 60Hz, 30-bit]

I can increase the resolution all the way up to 7680 x 4320 (8k) and the image is clear, but the monitor is still connect/synced at 5k and the System Profiler shows:

> 2024-03-31 12:46:57.626 system_profiler[43945:973094] Device PreExisted [000000010000076f] AMD Radeon RX 6600
> Resolution: 7680 x 4320 (4320p/8K UHD 2 - 8K Ultra High Definition)

System Profiler shows:

[image]

It's worth noting that my M2 MacBook Pro connected via Thunderbolt connects to the monitor at 6K @ 60Hz, 30-bit and the available resolutions in Sonoma are different that what I'm getting on the Mac Pro. For example, on the MacBook Pro, I can set the resolution all the way up to 6144 x 3456, or I can set it to half this, 3072 x 1728. Neither of these options are available on the Mac Pro in Monterey. It's hard to say for sure, but the Macbook Pro appears to be just a tad sharper.

So am I truly achieving 8K (surpassing 6k even), or am I running at 5K and just scaling?

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: @benwiggy I am running macOS Monterey via OCLP.

Comment: Impressive you’re getting 5k with HDMI. I would expect display port to be the only connection to get you to 5k and higher resolution. I haven’t seen a HBR3 mini display port cable, but monoprice cables is where I’d try even with their 4k cable if you can’t connect their DP to DP that supports HBR3 officially.

Comment: @bmike according to the Amazon listing, the mDP 16k cable I linked above is HBR3. Do you think my issue is cables? Given the PC works fine with the cables, I'm starting to think something is wrong with the card itself.

Comment: Will be hard to tell without more gear or a very expensive line analyzer @SwisherSweet